# HTML to nopCommerce theme

Tags: html, themes, nopcommerce

I am new to nopCommerce and trying to make HTML to theme on it I googled lots of things but not able to get proper way to create customized theme nopCommerce, can any one help,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The easiest way:

1. Copy the folder at `~/Themes/DarkOrange` to `~/Themes/YOUR_THEME`. Modify the corresponding items in theme.config.
2. If you need to change any view, copy that view from `~/Views/SUB_FOLDER/FILE_NAME.cshtml` and paste it under `~/Themes/YOUR_THEME/SUB_FOLDER/FILE_NAME.cshtml`.

   For example, if you want to change the code in `~/Views/Shared/_ColumnsOne.cshtml`, copy that file and paste it under `~/Themes/YOUR_THEME/Shared/_ColumnsOne.cshtml`.
3. If you do not need to change any view, then modifying `~/Themes/YOUR_THEME/Content/styles.css` is enough. (Also make sure you update `~/Themes/YOUR_THEME/Views/Shared/Head.cshtml` to point to your CSS)

**Rule of Thumb:** nopCommerce will look for the specific view in your theme. If it can't find the view then it falls back to the original views at `~/Views`. Otherwise your theme's views override the original views.

Comment: Please visit http://www.pronopcommerce.com/creating-an-nopcommerce-theme-the-definitive-guide for complete guide on creating nopCommerce themes. :D

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the Designers guide there are some nice articles describing why and how to use nopCommerce themes:

[Why nopCommerce Theme?](https://www.nop-templates.com/why-nopcommerce-themes)

[How to create nopCommerce themes](http://www.nop-templates.com/blog/12/how-to-create-nopcommerce-themes)

Answer (score 3):

A little help here: [Overview (Designer's Guide)](http://docs.nopcommerce.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1442505)

Answer (score 0):

Copy all the files inside `~/Views` to your Themes: `~/Themes/YourTheme/Views`

Then just modify any `.cshtml` file inside.

I hope it helps!

Comment: No. You do not need to copy all the files. Just copy the file that you want to change. If you don't need to change any, then you don't need to copy any.