# How to override a plugin's view from within the theme in nopCommerce 2.65?

Tags: nopcommerce

I would like to override, in nopCommerce 2.65, the views located in Nop.Plugin.Payments.Manual/Views/PaymentManual from within my custom theme.
My custom theme  is located Nop.Web/Themes and was developed using the information found in [HTML to nopCommerce theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12266717/html-to-nopcommerce-theme).

Is this possible?  or The only way to update a plugin's view is to update the source code of the plugin?

Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Have you found the answer to this question?

Comment: Note that since 3.40 it's impossible to override plugins' views. Physical path are now required http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/31404/views-and-themes-in-version-340.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be able to. 
The plugin will look for a view in these 4 locations:

```
~/Themes/MyTheme/Views/PaymentManual/Nop.Plugin.Payments.Manual.Views.PaymentManual.PaymentInfo.cshtml
~/Themes/MyTheme/Views/PaymentManual/Nop.Plugin.Payments.Manual.Views.PaymentManual.PaymentInfo.vbhtml
~/Themes/MyTheme/Views/Shared/Nop.Plugin.Payments.Manual.Views.PaymentManual.PaymentInfo.cshtml
~/Themes/MyTheme/Views/Shared/Nop.Plugin.Payments.Manual.Views.PaymentManual.PaymentInfo.vbhtml
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the views of the plugin are embedded views and you can't override them without modifying the source code of the plugin and recompiling it.